# Why drawing straight lines using Core Graphics I get "dashed" lines?

Tags: ios, swift, drawing, core-graphics

I have tried to draw an icon with the following swift code but I got "dashed" lines. I have just used `moveToPoint` and `addLineToPoint` functions. I got the same graphic glitch with other drawing too as you can see in the under images. I use Xcode 7.2 and run code on iOS 9.2.1.

```
@IBDesignable class DeleteButton: UIButton {

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        UIColor.blackColor().setStroke()
        let lineWidth = CGFloat(1)

        // Draw empty circle
        let frame = CGRect(x: rect.origin.x + lineWidth, y: rect.origin.y + lineWidth, width: rect.width - (lineWidth * 2), height: rect.height - (lineWidth * 2))
        let path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: frame)
        path.lineWidth = lineWidth

        path.stroke()

        // Draw X
        let radius = (rect.width / 2) * 0.5
        let center = CGPoint(x: rect.width / 2, y: rect.height / 2)

        let π = CGFloat(M_PI)
        let centerWidth = radius * cos(π/4)
        let centerHeight = radius * sin(π/4)

        path.lineWidth = lineWidth

        path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: CGFloat(center.x + centerWidth), y: CGFloat(center.y + centerHeight)))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: CGFloat(center.x - centerWidth), y: CGFloat(center.y - centerHeight)))
        path.stroke()

        path.lineWidth = lineWidth

        path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: center.x - centerWidth, y: center.y + centerHeight))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: center.x + centerWidth, y: center.y - centerHeight))
        path.stroke()
    }
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

I apologize for my bad english.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are seeing the result of the button's title text drawing over the image.  Check out the following demo using your code in a Playground:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We need to know the context in which that code runs. You can't just start drawing.

The usual way to draw in a view is to override the drawRect method. When you do that the system has the graphics context set up correctly with a mask that clips your drawing to the view's bounds, the coordinate system set up to the view's coordinates, etc.

If your drawing code is not in a view's drawRect method then that is your problem.

Comment: That's odd. The drawing context might have a line dash set, or there might be a mask active that is covering part of your drawing. Try using CGContextSetLineDash on the drawing context with a nil array and a count of 0. What happens if you just create a rectangular bezier path the size of the whole view and fill it with a solid color? Do you still see white on it?